# Wagtail (Django CMS) how to add single image in wagtail, simple attempt ends with "OperationalError no such column: gallery_gallerysubpage.cover_id"

Tags: django, image, model, wagtail

My problem is trivial, I just don't know how to add single image as Page miniature. Here's my page model (I tried like shown in [ImageChooserPanel reference](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/pages/panels.html)):

```
class GallerySubpage(Page):
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    # THIS IS TAKEN FROM DOCS
    cover = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    # This returns some dummy for a while. I want to replace this with some field that contain single Image
    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label = "Images that will be displayed on this page"),

        # THIS IS TAKEN FROM DOCS
        ImageChooserPanel('cover'),

    ]
```

When I run the code I get error:

```
OperationalError at /gallery/galerry132/
no such column: gallery_gallerysubpage.cover_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above error would happen if you didn't run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` after adding the `cover` field.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the models, rerun the following to make it effect:
- python manage.py makemigration
- python manage.py migrate
- python manage.py runserver